# Is there a way to remove "featured image" from a "medium.com" post?

Tags: medium.com-publishing-api, wordpress-featured-image

I want to remove featured image from one of my medium.com posts. I could not find any options to do it when I edit my post.
[Here](https://medium.com/@ashkan.abbasi/comparison-of-fast-deep-learning-based-object-detectors-eeac9a0a0ebb) is my post which I want to remove the image for it:

Answer (score 1):

There is no button or menu command to do this.  You have to click on the image, observe a thin green line surrounding it (which shows that you've selected it) and hit the "delete" (backspace) key on your keyboard.  If you're using an iPad or other portable device, I don't know how to do it; I'm using my MacBook Pro laptop.

Comment: As far as I remember, the feature image is created by medium itself and after you finish your story. I don't know whether this method can be used to remove it or not.